# Remove duplicate records based on multiple columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, duplicates, destroy

I'm using Heroku to host my Ruby on Rails application and for one reason or another, I may have some duplicate rows.

Is there a way to delete duplicate records based on 2 or more criteria but keep just 1 record of that duplicate collection?

In my use case, I have a Make and Model relationship for cars in my database.

```
Make      Model
---       ---
Name      Name
          Year
          Trim
          MakeId
```

I'd like to delete all Model records that have the same Name, Year and Trim but keep 1 of those records (meaning, I need the record but only once). I'm using Heroku console so I can run some active record queries easily.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
class Model

  def self.dedupe
    # find all models and group them on keys which should be common
    grouped = all.group_by{|model| [model.name,model.year,model.trim,model.make_id] }
    grouped.values.each do |duplicates|
      # the first one we want to keep right?
      first_one = duplicates.shift # or pop for last one
      # if there are any more left, they are duplicates
      # so delete all of them
      duplicates.each{|double| double.destroy} # duplicates can now be destroyed
    end
  end

end

Model.dedupe
```

- Find All
- Group them on keys which you need for uniqueness
- Loop on the grouped model's values of the hash
- remove the first value because you want to retain one copy
- delete the rest

Comment: This is in the Model model?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson it should be in whatever activerecord model you have.

Comment: Interesting method but a little inefficient with large set of records. Wondering if there is a way to do it with active record it self.

Comment: Works but extremely inefficient for large data sets. A much faster way is to use this algo to collect the ids in an array first and then use one DELETE FROM sql statement to delete the array of ids.

Answer (score 55):

If your User table data like below

```
User.all =>
[
    #<User id: 15, name: "a", email: "a@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:09", updated_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:09">, 
    #<User id: 16, name: "a1", email: "a@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:20", updated_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:20">, 
    #<User id: 17, name: "b", email: "b@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:28", updated_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:28">, 
    #<User id: 18, name: "b1", email: "b1@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:35", updated_at: "2013-08-06 08:57:35">, 
    #<User id: 19, name: "b11", email: "b1@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 09:01:30", updated_at: "2013-08-06 09:01:30">, 
    #<User id: 20, name: "b11", email: "b1@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-08-06 09:07:58", updated_at: "2013-08-06 09:07:58">] 
1.9.2p290 :099 >
```

Email id's are duplicate, so our aim is to remove all duplicate email ids from user table.

**Step 1:**

To get all distinct email records id.

```
ids = User.select("MIN(id) as id").group(:email,:name).collect(&:id)
=> [15, 16, 18, 19, 17]
```

**Step 2:**

To remove duplicate id's from user table with distinct email records id.

Now the ids array holds the following ids.

```
[15, 16, 18, 19, 17]
User.where("id NOT IN (?)",ids)  # To get all duplicate records
User.where("id NOT IN (?)",ids).destroy_all
```

** RAILS 4 **

ActiveRecord 4 introduces the `.not` method which allows you to write the following in Step 2:

```
User.where.not(id: ids).destroy_all
```

Comment: This is dangerous: running it again when you don't have dups will delete more than you want because the logic is "delete everything except D". I think the better logic is "delete everything in D", where D is the list of ids of duplicated rows.

Answer (score 19):

Similar to @Aditya Sanghi 's answer, but this way will be more performant because you are only selecting the duplicates, rather than loading every Model object into memory and then iterating over all of them.

```
# returns only duplicates in the form of [[name1, year1, trim1], [name2, year2, trim2],...]
duplicate_row_values = Model.select('name, year, trim, count(*)').group('name, year, trim').having('count(*) > 1').pluck(:name, :year, :trim)

# load the duplicates and order however you wantm and then destroy all but one
duplicate_row_values.each do |name, year, trim|
  Model.where(name: name, year: year, trim: trim).order(id: :desc)[1..-1].map(&:destroy)
end
```

Also, if you truly don't want duplicate data in this table, you probably want to add a multi-column unique index to the table, something along the lines of:

```
add_index :models, [:name, :year, :trim], unique: true, name: 'index_unique_models'
```

Answer (score 15):

You could try the following: (based on previous answers)

```
ids = Model.group('name, year, trim').pluck('MIN(id)')
```

to get all valid records. And then:

```
Model.where.not(id: ids).destroy_all
```

to remove the unneeded records. And certainly, you can make a migration that adds a unique index for the  three columns so this is enforced at the DB level:

```
add_index :models, [:name, :year, :trim], unique: true
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Wouldn't the second code block here just clear the whole table except for the ids found in the first code block?

Comment: That's what the OP was looking for, deleting all duplicates - the first method gets you all of the non-dupes

Answer (score 4):

To run it on a migration I ended up doing like the following (based on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124391/2667984) by @aditya-sanghi)

```rb
class AddUniqueIndexToXYZ < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # delete duplicates
    dedupe(XYZ, 'name', 'type')

    add_index :xyz, [:name, :type], unique: true
  end

  def dedupe(model, *key_attrs)
    model.select(key_attrs).group(key_attrs).having('count(*) > 1').each { |duplicates|
      dup_rows = model.where(duplicates.attributes.slice(key_attrs)).to_a
      # the first one we want to keep right?
      dup_rows.shift

      dup_rows.each{ |double| double.destroy } # duplicates can now be destroyed
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: You could add `model.unscoped` to queries to avoid being caught on default scope not being present on the current group query.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@aditya-sanghi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124391/311657), with a more efficient way to find duplicates using SQL.

Add this to your `ApplicationRecord` to be able to deduplicate any model:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # …

  def self.destroy_duplicates_by(*columns, order: :id)
    groups = select(columns).group(columns).having(Arel.star.count.gt(1))
    groups.each do |duplicate|
      records = where(duplicate.attributes.symbolize_keys.slice(*columns))
      records.limit(nil).order(order).offset(1).destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```

You can then call `destroy_duplicates_by` to destroy all records (except the first) that have the same values for the given columns. For example:

```rb
Model.destroy_duplicates_by(:name, :year, :trim)
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose a slightly safer route (IMHO). I started by getting all the unique records.

```rb
    ids = Model.where(other_model_id: 1).uniq(&:field).map(&:id)
```

Then I got all the ids

```rb
    all_ids = Model.where(other_model_id: 1).map(&:id)
```

This allows me to do a matrix subtraction for the duplicates

```rb
    dups = all_ids - ids
```

I then map over the duplicate ids and fetch the model because I want to ensure I have the records I am interested in.

```rb
    records = dups.map do |id| Model.find(id) end
```

When I am sure I want to delete, I iterate again to delete.

```rb
    records.map do |record| record.delete end
```

When deleting duplicate records on a production system, you want to be very sure you are not deleting important live data, so in this process, I can double-check everything.

So in the case above:

```rb
    all_ids =  Model.all.map(&:ids)

    uniq_ids = Model.all.group_by do |model|
      [model.name, model.year, model.trim] 
    end.values.map do |duplicates|
      duplicates.first.id
    end

    dups = all_ids - uniq_ids

    records = dups.map { |id| Model.find(id) }

    records.map { |record| record.delete }
```

or something like this.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this sql query, to remove all duplicate records but latest one

```
DELETE FROM users USING users user WHERE (users.name = user.name AND users.year = user.year AND users.trim = user.trim AND users.id < user.id);
```

Comment: This will remove all.