# Why doesn't this ruby rails statement works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a parent model that has many child models

I want to destroy duplicate child records based on one parameter of the child.

I tried this:

```
 parent.child.uniq! {|child| child.parameter }
```

It apparently works but the database does not reflects the change.

Comment: Did you try saving the record to the database after changing it?

Comment: mbratch,how would you do that? I tried parent.save and parent.child.save but neither of those worked.

Comment: My question back is, if you're using a database and running into duplicates in a field that should be unique, why don't you have a unique index on it that enforces that constraint? Let the DBM do its job, and rely on it to do it. Rails is designed for that sort of behavior and makes it easy to design in.

Answer (score 1):

Your operation is performed on an object retrieved from database and not the actual database.  Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124212/remove-duplicate-records-based-on-multiple-columns) for the right answer.

Comment: this does not works   grouped.values.each throws an association error

Comment: just tried, works just fine for me.  perhaps try the second solution on that page, it's a bit easier to follow

Comment: that algorithm deletes the duplicates of the model itself, not the duplicates of child for each instance of the parent model.

Comment: solution: grouped = child.group_by{ , instead of: grouped = all.group_by{

Comment: did you try it as it is?