# Delete duplicate records based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, duplicates, rails-activerecord

In our system we run hourly imports from an external database. Due to an error in the import scripts, there are now some duplicate records.

A duplicate is deemed where any record has the same `:legacy_id` and `:company`.

What code can I run to find and delete these duplicates?

I was playing around with this:

```
Product.select(:legacy_id,:company).group(:legacy_id,:company).having("count(*) > 1")
```

It seemed to return some of the duplicates, but I wasn't sure how to delete from there?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124212/remove-duplicate-records-based-on-multiple-columns this helps?

Comment: That worked great @argentum47 can't believe I missed that when I was browsing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

```
Product.where.not(
  id: Product.group(:legacy_id, :company).pluck('min(products.id)')
).delete_all
```

Or pure sql:

```
delete from products
where id not in ( 
   select min(p.id) from products p group by p.legacy_id, p.company
)
```

Comment: If you have associated records that you want to delete as well, use `destroy_all` instead of `delete_all`