# Unable to Delete Record of My Comment Object

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-commentable

Suppose my Rails app have a relationship of Recipe and Comment by using [acts_as_commentable_with_threading](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading) gem and that Recipe gem has [paranoid2](https://github.com/anjlab/paranoid2) gem configured. Migrating from old system to new system, I've created new records by manually inserting records to the Comment table, but mistakenly created duplicate comments for every recipe. Now I wanted to remove the duplicate records by modifying the solution of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124212/remove-duplicate-records-based-on-multiple-columns).

```
# app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_commentable
  paranoid

  # other configurations and methods

end


# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  paranoid

  def self.dedupe_recipe_comments
    grouped = all.where(commentable_type: "Recipe").group_by{|model| [model.commentable_id,model.body,model.user_id,model.commentable_username] }
    grouped.values.each do |duplicates|
      first_one = duplicates.shift

      duplicates.each do |double| 
      puts "removing #{double.inspect} from table"
      double.destroy(force: true)
    end

  end

end
```

But when I call this function in my Rails console, this function returns an error, let's say the first duplicated record has an `id` of 1480:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=1480
>   from /Users/yoonwaiyan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'

But when I tried to find the record in the same console using `Comment.find(1480)`, it returns a record:

```
#<Comment id: 1480, commentable_id: 51, commentable_type: "Recipe", body: "comment content", user_id: 0, parent_id: nil, lft: nil, rgt: nil, created_at: "2006-05-16 18:48:03", updated_at: "2015-07-25 16:17:17", status: "approved", deleted_at: nil, commentable_username: "user1">
```

And then I tried to destroy in the console:

```
Comment.find(1480).destroy(force: true)
```

It returns the same error:

> Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `comments`.* FROM `comments`  WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`id` = 1480 LIMIT 1
>
> (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>
> SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`id` = 1480
>
> Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `comments`.* FROM `comments`  WHERE `comments`.`id` = 1480 LIMIT 1
>
> (12.5ms)  ROLLBACK
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=1480
>   from /Users/yoonwaiyan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'

This error is weird and I couldn't find any proper solution on both gem and Stack Overflow. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: and without the force? Comment.find(1480).destroy()

Comment: .destroy! is the real destroy method for paranoid gem, afair

Comment: @huanson it worked but not my preferred way. Soft delete is not desirable for big database in my case.