# Rails - How to delete all but one record that meet a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a table as such

```
    id user_id  value
     1   1       A
     2   1        A
     3   1       A
     4   1       A
     5   1       A
     6   1       A
     7   2       B
     8   2       B
     9   3       C
```

As you can see, there are many duplicates in this table. For each duplicate, I want to be able to delete all but one of them, such that I am still left with one record for each of the duplicated records. For example, for the duplicate records with `user_id = 1` and `value = A`, I want to be able to delete all but one of these so that I am still left with one record with the values of `user_id = 1` and `value = A`

Comment: what is the primary key of this table?

Comment: @mrzasa how does it matter (I am not even mentioning table might have _no_ PK at all)?

Comment: My idea is to find first repetition and then delete the rest of them distinguishing them by PK that must be unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate records based on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124212/remove-duplicate-records-based-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_columns_index (user_id, value)` should work. Later you might remove this index, if not needed.

Comment: Sorry! Updated with PK

Comment: @UmeshMalhotra OMG, what if the table contains 1B records?

Comment: If you have a lot of records to process, you should [let the database do this work for you](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/). This could make the difference between the process taking seconds versus minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with moveson that the best approach would be to define an index within the database to either enforce distinct records or allow you to add a [uniqueness validator to the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424154/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-two-columns-together).

Another option would be to intercept the ActiveRecord create method call to prevent duplicates:

```
class Example < ApplicationRecord
  def self.create( attributes = nil, &block )
    attributes.each {|attr| self.create(attr, &block) } if attributes.is_a? Array
    return if find_by attributes
    super attributes, &block
  end
end
```

The basic idea here is to abort if you already see a record with the same attribute values in the database...  but then let ActiveRecord continue to do all the heavy lifting by calling it with super.

If there's a situation where for some reason you can't exercise control over the database to prevent duplicates from being entered, you could try an approach where you create a class method to periodically purge the duplicates from the system.

Here's an example of a method that would iterate over the entire recordset and use a hash to track whether it has seen the values before, removing them if so:

```
class Example < ApplicationRecord
  def self.dedup
    distinct = {}
    all.each do |row|
      if distinct[row.user_id] && distinct[row.user_id] == row.value
        row.delete
      else
        distinct[row.user_id] = row.value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You could then call it like so: `Example.dedup` whenever you wished to purge the duplicate records.

For those looking to follow along at home, you can use the following migration:

```
rails g model example user_id:integer value:string
```

and seed file:

```
examples = Example.create([
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 1, value: 'A'},
  {user_id: 2, value: 'B'},
  {user_id: 2, value: 'B'},
  {user_id: 3, value: 'C'},
])
```